# GZIP files in agnular

Tags: nodes, gzip

I have an angular and in google page insights it shows me to gzip to improve performance I have the following code in the nginx/config file

```
gzip_vary on; 
gzip_min_length 10240; 
gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth; 
gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml; 
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
```

I also have a node server.ts file for that uses the angular universal express engine for the
Server-Side-Rendering used the compression middleware but that did'nt work any

Comment: Did you restart nginx? Have you verified using another tool? (Gzip compression test).

Comment: I did restart the nginx and i tested with some only tools and it says nginx not enabled